# Implementing subtype in traits throws error "Expected class or Object Defination"

Tags: scala, traits

I am trying to replicate the subtyping of traits in Scala using IntelliJ. I debugged the below code throws a couple of errors. What am I doing wrong here

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

trait Pet {
  val name: String
}

class Cat(val name: String) extends Pet
class Dog(val name: String) extends Pet

val dog = new Dog("Harry")
val cat = new Cat("Sally")

object Animals {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val animals = ArrayBuffer.empty[Pet]
    animals.append(dog)
    animals.append(cat)
    animals.foreach(pet => println(pet.name)
  }
}
```

I get below errors

> Error:(10, 1) expected class or object definition
>   val dogs=new Dogs("Harry")
>   Error:(11, 1) expected class or object definition
>   val cats=new Cats("Sally")

Comment: Your snippet should work fine if you place `val dog = new Dog("Harry")` and `val cat = new Cat("Sally")` within the `main` method.

Comment: Thank you it works